# Update ini file using conf file data using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have below 2 files a.conf and b.ini.
File a.conf has drivers path in it. Which needs to be updated in b.ini file against that particular driver.

a.conf

```
#find driver directory and replace that

oracle=/client64/lib #bla bla
db2=/opt/db2/lib

#dvs=/opt/dvs/lib
```

b.ini

```
[SQLSERVER]
Driver = /opt/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
HOST = 192.168.220.156
PORT = 1433
TDS_VERSION = 8.0

[ORACLE]
Driver=/usr/lib/oracle/19.5/client64/lib/libsqora.so.19.1
HOST = 192.168.220.182
PORT = 1521
```

I have to write a shell script in such a way that it must read all the values which are not commented in file a.conf and update the path of Driver in b.ini file.
I am new to shell script any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I'd look into a language with a library for reading Windows style INI files instead of using a shell script.

Comment: To add to @Shawn's comment, Python has a library that does this for you, in a one liner.  I did that transition from bash to Python since I had a large number of ini files to process.